# Git merge doesn't use default merge message, opens editor with default message

Tags: git, git-merge

How can I force `git merge` to use the default merge message instead of loading my editor with said message?

I have no editor listed in `git config -l`, so I'm not sure why it opens an editor.

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't merge - as commit - have the option `--no-edit`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Found the answer after some digging

EDIT: As per Mark's suggestion, this is the best way to do so:

```
git config --global core.mergeoptions --no-edit
```

Comment: Rather than edit `~/.gitconfig` directly, it might be safer to suggest using `git config` to do this, e.g. `git config --global core.mergeoptions --no-edit`, so that there's no chance of creating a malformed `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: This seems to work for `git merge`'s, but I'm still having an editor open up for `git pull`'s. Is there any way to disable the commit message for this as well?

Comment: I can't find any mention of `core.mergeoptions`, though it certainly applies to `branch.*.mergeoptions`. Does anyone know the supported versions for this?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Both merge and pull still bring up an editor on non-ff merges.  Using git 1.7.10.4

Comment: Interesting, this is NOT working for me with 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37).

Comment: I'm still having no issues and am now on a new computer, and currently running git version 2.2.1. For those not having any success, I'd imagine you have some sort of conflicting git option, or that you perhaps have multiple gitconfigs

Comment: A trip through the git source and release notes suggests that there is not now and never was a `core.mergeoptions`.  There is, however, a `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` that was added to git 1.7.10 when `git merge` itself was changed to bring up the editor.  There are also options available as `branch.*.mergeoptions`, as @cmbuckley noted.

Answer (score 74):

Use

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
```

or

```
git merge --no-edit
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted, but it forces you to type --no-edit every time. The solution I found changes the default behavior of `git merge`

Comment: Passing it directly to the merge command, as suggested here, is specially useful in a script that invokes git merge. You almost always want a script not to prompt the user. However, it'd be nice to know how to pass a custom message to `git merge`. Perhaps `git merge -m "message"` works but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: For me, `export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` worked (for merges) when the accepted answer (`git config --global core.mergeoptions --no-edit`) did not.

Answer (score 12):

This is a new feature of Git, [introduced in Git 1.7.10](https://git-blame.blogspot.com/2012/02/anticipating-git-1710.html), to use the old one (don't provide a message on merge) put these two lines in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

```
GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`git merge --no-ff --no-edit -m "my custom merge message" somebranch`