# Configure git mergeoptions --no-edit on all branches

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to configure git to always accept the default merge message when merging (with option --no-edit). I found this answer ([Git merge doesn't use default merge message, opens editor with default message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752288/git-merge-doesnt-use-default-merge-message-opens-editor-with-default-message/13919062#13919062?newreg=d55cb6c7b5fb40d7abdd5c1215389647)) but it doesn't work for me, and it is not listed in the manual ([git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)).

The following configuration (with an actual branch name rather than "*") does work for a single branch, but I need the configuration on all branches, so I tried this, to no avail.

```
[branch "*"]
    mergeoptions = --no-edit
```

Is there any global configuration to do this ?

**EDIT**

While searching I found the **branch "*"** configuration was proposed a while back as a patch, but never implemented ([[PATCH] Add default merge options for all branches](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-Add-default-merge-options-for-all-branches-td6324710.html)).

Comment: Try the `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` environment variable mentioned in the other question.  Or, if it's OK, make yourself an alias: `git config --global alias.nm 'merge --no-edit'` and then use `git nm` (feel free to use some other name, `nm` is not a great name :-) ).

Comment: I would have preferred a git configuration, but the GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no environment variable works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Overriding the `merge` command with an alias that appends `--no-edit` seems to work:

```
[alias]
    merge = merge --no-edit
```