# Avoid vi "PopUp" when merging

Tags: git

Sometimes git opens `vi` and shows me a message like this:

```
Merge branch 'master' into feature/heal-the-world

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

I always close the `vi` unchanged.

Is there a way to avoid this "vi PopUp"?

I would like to stay with my current workflow, I just want git to automatically do this. I don't want to switch to rebase.

**Update**

since some calls to `git` get done in scripts, I need a way to change the default behaviour of git. An alias which does what I need does not help here.

Answer (score 3):

one-time setup:

```
git config --global alias.gm='-c core.editor=true merge'
```

from then on:

```
git gm
```

Comment: I updated the question: since some calls to `git` get done in scripts, I need a way to change the default behaviour of git. An alias which does what I need does not help here.

Comment: @jthill Do you mean `alias.gm`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [--no-edit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-edit) argument, to accept the auto-generated message.

```
git merge other_branch --no-edit
```

Unfortunately, there is no simple solution to make this the default behavior for all branches, as you can see in [Configure git mergeoptions --no-edit on all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462256/configure-git-mergeoptions-no-edit-on-all-branches). You can either specify this for all branches, or use an alias that will shadow the default merge, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782300/2266261

Comment: I updated the question: since some calls to `git` get done in scripts, I need a way to change the default behaviour of git. An alias which does what I need does not help here.

Comment: @guettli in that case, I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782300/2266261 is the simplest solution