# Stop git merge from opening text editor

Tags: git, merge

Every time I run a git merge command it opens the text editor asking me to add an extra message.

How can I stop git from opening the editor & simply merging my branches?  Because when it opens the editor it doesn't complete the merge, even if I add an extra message & save the file, the terminal just hangs on my git merge command.

```
Merge branch 'my-feature-branch' into main-development

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
# 
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git merge doesn't use default merge message, opens editor with default message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752288/git-merge-doesnt-use-default-merge-message-opens-editor-with-default-message)

Comment: "when it opens the editor it doesn't complete the merge, even if I add an extra message & save the file, the terminal just hangs on my git merge command." This is likely a bigger problem. When you do a non-merge commit do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: @dtech it's similar but not the same, same same but different :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the `--no-edit` option, you can read about it in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

Note that using the default message is discuraged, since it provides no meaningful information about the changes introduced with this merge.

---

On a sidenote: To continue merging you probably have to close the editor.

---

If you have a git version prior to `1.7.8` there is still a way to achieve what you want by using the `env` command.

```
env GIT_EDITOR=: git merge <ref-you-want-to-merge>
```

For easier usage you could create an alias.

```
git config --global alias.merge-no-edit '!env GIT_EDITOR=: git merge'
```

Which then can be used using `git merge-no-edit <ref-you-want-to-merge>`.

Comment: Do you know what version of git this was added to - we have CentOS 6 servers running git 1.7.1 and they do not support the `--no-edit` option.

Comment: @HamishDowner while it seems that there are no particular release notes which introduce the `--no-edit` option, [it's mentioned in the `1.7.10` release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt#L23-L26) saying that it can be used with "Git version 1.7.8 or newer". I'll edit my answer to include a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: Just found that the [1.7.8 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L85) mention the `--edit` option, so that implies the --no-edit option.

Comment: The correct way is to do `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no  git merge <branch>` instead of unsetting `GIT_EDITOR` [see this](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-options#merge-options---no-edit).

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```
git merge --no-edit
```

This is the man page :

> --edit, -e, --no-edit
>              Invoke an editor before committing successful mechanical merge to further edit the auto-generated merge message, so that the
>   user can explain and justify the merge. The --no-edit option can be used to accept the auto-generated message (this is generally discouraged). The --edit (or -e) option is still useful if
>   you are giving a draft message with the -m option from the command
>   line and want to edit it in the editor.
>
> Older scripts may depend on the historical behaviour of not allowing the user to edit the merge log message. They will see an
>   editor opened when they run git merge. To make it easier to adjust
>              such scripts to the updated behaviour, the environment variable GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT can be set to no at the beginning of them.

Comment: NOTE: To merge another branch or ref into the current branch, the branch name must come *after* the `--no-edit` option like this: `git merge --no-edit origin/my-feautre-branch` -- The order of these arguments matters. The editor will still open if passing the ref first.

Answer (score 13):

Add the following line into your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file:

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
```