# How to save commit changes without editing when doing a merge in a script?

Tags: bash, git

I wonder how to add in my basic script some commands with nano, Ctrl-O, Enter, Ctrl-X, Enter. You can see what I want at the end of the script. It is after git merge, I just need to save commit changes (formality)

```
#!/bin/bash

## Set Local Rebase ##
git config pull.rebase true

## Update OpenWRT Scripts
./scripts/feeds update -a
./scripts/feeds install -a

## 5.4 kernel
git remote add wrt https://github.com/james/openwrt.git
git fetch james
git checkout -b wrt james/kernel5.4-qsdk10.0
git checkout master
git merge wrt
*ctrl o*
*enter*
*ctrl x*
*enter*
```

Comment: What do these commands achieve in nano? Do I understand correctly that you want to save the file without editing it and exit nano?

Comment: This is not impossible, but would be a lot of work, since application usually won't be running interactively in a script. Could you tell us more about why you want to do that? This seems like an instance of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Consider taking a look at the `git merge` man page and thinking about how you could use options like `--no-edit`.

Comment: thanks guys, yes it is after git merge, I just need to save commit changes (formality)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stop git merge from opening text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609146/stop-git-merge-from-opening-text-editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to interact with your editor to set the merge commit message, you can use the `-m` flag to specify a commit message without opening an editor, or the `--no-edit` to accept the default message. You can also use `git fmt-merge-msg` to help generate a message to pass to `-m`, but that's a bit harder.

Using --no-edit:

```
git merge --no-edit
```

Using `-m`:

```
git merge -m "automated merge by my script"
```