# Git commit: disable opening editor

Tags: git, git-commit

`git commit` has a `--no-edit` flag which will "use the selected commit message without launching an editor".

For example, when `git merge` produces conflicts, after these have been resolved running `git commit --no-edit` will commit without opening the editor, using to the default merge commit message.

I want a way to permanently enforce this behaviour so I don't have to specify `--no-edit` each time I run `git commit`.

I can find an equivalent setting for [`git merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752465/5932012), but nothing for `git commit`.

Answer (score 1):

For `git commit` the `--no-edit` option only makes sense if there *is* a "selected commit message". In case of committing a merge conflict resolution or when being used together with `--amend` it's clear that the selected commit message is the one of the merge commit or the commit to amend to. But in the regular case of using `git commit` to create a new commit, you *have* to specify a commit message (unless `--allow-empty` is used), hence you *have* to use an editor. So as the use cases for `git commit --no-edit` are rather limited, I'm not aware of a permanent configuration setting for that behavior. In any case, you could define your own [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for it.